# Autolayout multi line label in a table cell with fix height

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have a table view with fixed height cells. In the cell there are 3 labels; name, address and type. The name label can be 1 or 2 lines while other 2 labels are only 1 line. I want to come up with something as in the screenshot. When the name label is 2 lines, it decreases the padding on the top and bottom of the cell.

So, I set the constraints between labels to be equal to some constant number. And also used inequality constraints between the name label and the cell's contentView. It actually worked and produced the screen below. But it gives me ambiguous layout in autolayoutTrace for the all 3 labels. I guess my inequality constraints are causing the problem.

How can I achieve this screen properly?

[image: screenshot of tableview]

Comment: How about using a single `UILabel`, with `attributedText`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that height of all labels are fixed and will not change in future then it seems you are doing in correct way. For ambiguous layout you may have sent some constraint that are not required or conflicting, you can debug constraints and make necessary changes. Reference :[Debug Constraints](http://www.battestini.net/blog/2013/04/13/ios-autolayout-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

put the two labels in a container. Then set left margin, right margin, and center Y alignment constraints on the container.